# Python: Is there a way to position a watermark (which is a pdf itself) on pdf pages?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I would like to place a watermark (which is a `.pdf`) itself on the top right corner of every single one of my `.pdf` pages.

As reference I wrote a script that does just that, but for `.png` files but I just wasn't able to this with `.pdf`s.

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import webbrowser

# ============================ configure ============================
inputPath = 'input.pdf'
outputPath = 'output.pdf'
imgPath = 'logo.png'
tempPath = 'temp.pdf'
imgSize = 70
x = 500
y = 760
# ====================================================================

# Create temporary pdf and position image in it
c = canvas.Canvas(tempPath)
c.drawImage(imgPath, x, y, width=imgSize, height=imgSize)
c.save()

# read
tempFile = PdfFileReader(open(tempPath, "rb")).getPage(0)
outputFile = PdfFileWriter()
inputFile = PdfFileReader(open(inputPath, "rb"))

# merge onto every page from input
for i in range(inputFile.getNumPages()):
    page = inputFile.getPage(i)
    page.mergePage(tempFile)
    outputFile.addPage(page)

with open(outputPath, "wb") as out:
    outputFile.write(out)

# open pdf in default browser
webbrowser.open(outputPath)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to add a watermark: https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/add-watermark.html

```py
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Union, Literal, List

from pypdf import PdfWriter, PdfReader


def watermark(
    content_pdf: Path,
    stamp_pdf: Path,
    pdf_result: Path,
    page_indices: Union[Literal["ALL"], List[int]] = "ALL",
):
    reader = PdfReader(content_pdf)
    if page_indices == "ALL":
        page_indices = list(range(0, len(reader.pages)))

    writer = PdfWriter()
    for index in page_indices:
        content_page = reader.pages[index]
        mediabox = content_page.mediabox

        # You need to load it again, as the last time it was overwritten
        reader_stamp = PdfReader(stamp_pdf)
        image_page = reader_stamp.pages[0]

        image_page.merge_page(content_page)
        image_page.mediabox = mediabox
        writer.add_page(image_page)

    with open(pdf_result, "wb") as fp:
        writer.write(fp)
```